# Difference between Object.Destroy() and GameObject.Destroy() in Unity

Tags: unity, gameobject, objects

What is the difference between using `Object.Destroy()` and `GameObject.Destroy()` in Unity?

I found the following info about that: [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unityengine-object-destroy-not-deleting-gameobject.56788/) and [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html), but it did not answer my question.

So, could someone explain the matter foolproof, please?

Comment: AFAIK, they are the same. If you look at [the documentation page of `GameObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.html), the `Destroy` function is inherited from parent class (which is `Object`)

Comment: @Hellium it's a simple answer, but still worth posting as an answer that can be marked Accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None. `GameObject.Destroy()` is inherited from `Object.Destroy()`. Both statements refer to the same method.

This is *not* explicitly clear in the [official API documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.html), but most programmers can assume that to be the case based on the fact that both `GameObject` and `Object` contain the method, and `GameObject` inherits from `Object`. It can then be confirmed through IDEs or through the [*unofficial decompied source-code by MattRix on GitHub*](https://github.com/MattRix/UnityDecompiled) ([`GameObject`'s source code](https://github.com/MattRix/UnityDecompiled/blob/b4b209f8d1c93d66f560bf23c81bc0910cef177c/UnityEngine/UnityEngine/GameObject.cs) does not contain the `Destroy()` method, meaning it can only come from inheritance).

As such, you will also find the `Destroy()` method on anything else in the inheritance tree of `Object`. For example, `Component` also inherits from `Object`, and so you can add a `Destroy()` statement within any component's code, without explicitly including `Object.` before it.

<sup><sub>Note: My answer is independent, but some credits to [Hellium](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/92160/hellium) for answering correctly first in the OP.</sub></sup>